# Deleting pointer before returning value from function

Tags: c++

If I have this:

```
double foo()
{
double* ptr = new double(0);

return *ptr;
}
```

If ptr is not deleted before returning, this will cause a memory leak? Therefore, what is the correct way to delete ptr before returning from the function?

Comment: Yep, that would cause a memory leak, however, it seems like a bad example anyway... you don't need to allocate new memory just to have a double.

Comment: I would suggest:  void foo(double *d); and pass in the pointer which you can just set the value to inside the function and manage the memory afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

You have several solutions:

- scoped_ptr
- declaring a variable on the stack

Comment: And if `scoped_ptr` isn't available, `auto_ptr` will do in a pinch. This is the one use case where it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: And only use `scoped_ptr` or `auto_ptr` if `unique_ptr` isn't available.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the object (as opposed to its value) to exist beyond the scope of the function, then it doesn't make much sense to dynamically-allocate it.

Just allocate it on the stack:

```
double foo() {
    double d = 0;

    ...

    return d;
}
```

The alternative is to let the object exist beyond the scope of the function, in which case you don't want to delete it before returning.  The best way to manage this is with some kind of smart pointer (this handles memory management automatically in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning the value pointed by `ptr` then you definitely do **not** want to delete it before leaving the function. If you delete it and then return it, the calling function will try to access memory that has been freed, and this is forbidden.

Comment: He's de-referencing the pointer before returning, so he's getting the value. Note that the return type is `double` not `double*`.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK as long as you receive the return value of foo() in a pointer in the same class you are calling the function from. Afterwards you can use delete on that pointer when you don't need it anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you allocating a double dynamically?  I can't think of any
context where `new double` would make sense.  Just declare the `double`
as a local variable.

About the only time you'd want to allocate an object dyamically whose
lifetime ends at the end of the function would be if polymorphism is
involved.  In those cases, you can use `std::auto_ptr` (or 
`std::unique_ptr` if you're sure that all of the compilers you will ever
see will support C++11).